# How to add link to source code in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

[image]

```
class torch.FloatStorage[source]
    byte()
        Casts this storage to byte type
    char()
        Casts this storage to char type
```

Im trying to get some documentation done, i have managed to to get the format like the one shown above, But im not sure how to give that link of source code which is at the end of that function!
The link takes the person to the file which contains the code,But im not sure how to do it,

Comment: Just pointing out that [`pdoc`](https://pdoc.dev/) makes it by default

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is achieved thanks to one of the builtin sphinx extension.

The one you are looking for in [`spinx.ext.viewcode`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/viewcode.html). To enable it, add the string `'sphinx.ext.viewcode'` to the list `extensions` in your `conf.py` file.

In summary, you should see something like that in `conf.py`

```
extensions = [
    # other extensions that you might already use
    # ...
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
]
```

Comment: You still need to "list" the routines somehow. This can be done using another extension: [`sphinx.ext.autodoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html). You will find examples of use in the link. Given your original question, it appeared that you had the doc working but not the link to the source, hence my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the [`linkcode`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/linkcode.html) extension too.  Allows you to build a full HTTP link to the code on GitHub or such like.  This is sometimes a better option that including the code within the documentation itself.  (E.g. may have stronger permission on it than the docs themselves.)

You write a little helper function in your `conf.py` file, and it does the rest.

What I **really** like about `linkcode` is that it creates links for enums, enum values, and data elements, which I could not get to be linked with `viewcode`.

I extended the link building code to use `#:~:text=` to cause the linked-to page to scroll to the text.  Not perfect, as it will only scroll to the first instance, which may not always be correct, but likely 80~90% of the time it will be.

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

def linkcode_resolve(domain, info):
    # print(f"domain={domain}, info={info}")
    if domain != 'py':
        return None
    if not info['module']:
        return None
    filename = quote(info['module'].replace('.', '/'))
    if not filename.startswith("tests"):
        filename = "src/" + filename
    if "fullname" in info:
        anchor = info["fullname"]
        anchor = "#:~:text=" + quote(anchor.split(".")[-1])
    else:
        anchor = ""

    # github
    result = "https://<github>/<user>/<repo>/blob/master/%s.py%s" % (filename, anchor)
    # print(result)
    return result
```